# Can I still interrogate an informant that fights back?

Tags: batman-arkham-knight

A new mechanic was introduced in this game.  In previous games, interrogating an informant would always reveal locations of Riddler puzzles.  However this time, there's a chance where an informant would fight back and attack you.

Countering the attack seems to always knock him out.  I think when I initially saw this happen, I was surprised and he hit me and ran off.

**Is there a way to counter the attack so that I can still interrogate him afterward?**

Comment: I haven't had this happen to me yet, so I cant give a full answer but have you tried dodging instead of countering?  That way you could avoid doing any damage to the thug.

Comment: I don't think that was an option. It was essentially a mini-QTE as far as I could tell.  Everything was in slow-motion and zoomed in, with the counter indicators over the informant.  It only happened to be twice so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this happen about 10 times now, I'd say 10% of the time the informant tries to fight back during the interrogation.  Every time, if I successfully countered, the informant would cough up the info.  If I fail the counter (or hit some other key) I knock him out with no new riddler information.

[image: counter indicator about to pop up]

I'd suspect what happened in your case is that you failed the counter - it's a very short window, and pressing any other key (like B to skip the dialog) tends to fail it automatically.

Comment: What's the timing? Every time he breaks away and the counter indicators show, I hit the counter button and he's always knocked out.  He never just grabs him again.

Comment: @JeffMercado, every time I see the counter indicator, I counter, and Batman knocks him down and pins him, then he yields and I get the clues.

Comment: Ah, you know what, I'm not getting the right prompts. I was able to get him the moment he refused.  Though there was no prompt then.  If he breaks away, then I missed my chance.  Maybe part of the glitchiness of the PC version?

Comment: @JeffMercado, perhaps...  I always see the indicator immediately after he refuses, and I'm also playing the PC version.  Maybe it's a lag thing on your PC?  I have my settings set pretty low (720p, everything set to low or off) so perhaps that makes a difference?

Comment: I tuned things down too to delay the inevitable crash. But still running at 1920x1080. What GPU do you have by chance? I'm running Titan Blacks in SLI but running in Single GPU mode. Fairly stable but that initial prompt isn't showing for me.

Comment: I've found that the counter indicator is sometimes off screen due to the camera angle - it is still above his head but often that is off the top of the screen. The first few times it happened I just assumed that I had reached a limit of how many clues I could get from interrogating thugs and it was its way of telling me I can't get any more. One thing I did notice is that after a failed interrogation they are no longer marked green but when I did a batmobile takedown once he did go green during the animation and I think (though I may be wrong) that I got a "hit Y to interrogate" option. [xbox]

Comment: @JeffMercado, I have a Radeon 7950.  I'll agree with Chris that sometimes the prompt is most of the way off the screen.  It's been fairly obvious to me nonetheless, though.

Comment: Ok, maybe I just wasn't looking at it close enough, the counter indicators are mostly off screen but the feint halo is visible. I was certain those didn't appear before, but I did tweak my graphics settings since when I initially asked the question so who knows.

Comment: @JeffMercado: Now I know they are there I see them every time so I suspect they did appear before but now you know what you are looking for you actually see them rather than your brain ignoring it (I'm on xbox so definitely no changed settings).

Answer (score 2):

When interrogating an informant, there's a chance that he refuses and swings at you.  This is your chance to counter his counter so you can complete the interrogation.  You will get the counter prompts but it will be mostly off screen since the camera is zoomed in.  It's not super obvious but if you look close enough, you'll see it's there.

I've recorded a video to see.

If you miss your chance to counter, he'll just hit you and the fight will continue.  However he will change back to normal colors because he won't tell you anything anymore.  You'll just have to knock him out.